# Pandas copy values from sliced columns to sliced columns

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame `df` is as below:

```
idx    colA    colB    colC    colD
-----------------------------------
A1     foo1    bar1      
A2                     foo2    bar2
```

I would like to copy/move the data of `A2` from `colC:colD` to `colA:colB`:

```
idx    colA    colB    colC    colD
-----------------------------------
A1     foo1    bar1      
A2     foo2    bar2
```

I thought it was simple and tried `df.loc['A2','colA':'colB'] = df.loc['A2','colC':'colD']` but it didn't work.

However, I was able to do it one by one. For example, `df.loc['A2','colA'] = df.loc['A2','colC']` indeed changed `colA` to `foo2`. I could also assign **new values** to `colA` and `colB` by using the slicing expression `df.loc['A2','colA':'colB'] = 'FB'`:

```
idx    colA    colB    colC    colD
-----------------------------------
A1     foo1    bar1      
A2     FB      FB
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is same number of columns in both selects convert second Series to numpy array:

```
df.loc['A2','colA':'colB'] = df.loc['A2','colC':'colD'].to_numpy()
```